# How to fix "free(): invalid next size (normal) | Canceled (memory dump written)" in C

Tags: c, free, memcpy

I am writing a program which actually send raw Packets and Sniffing the Network. I have the Program to build, to send the Packets and to Sniff the Network. Each of them work (mostly) great. If i try to implement a main function which calls first the Function to build and send the Packet and after that the function which sniff, I get a `free(): Invalid next size (normal) | Cancelled (memory dump written)` Error.

I tried to find the Problem by my own. I called the `startSniffer()` - Function in different places. Actually in `send_tcp_packet` befor building the tcp Packet (`build_tcp_packet`), and after that too. If I call `startSniffer()` Function befor `build_tcp_packet` it works. So I call the `startSniffer()` - Function in `build_tcp_packet` befor `memcpy(...)` and it works. So I assume that the error is because of `memcpy(...)`. I removed `memcpy(...)` and the Programm works well. But actually the Programm needs `memcpy(...)` to set the Payload in TCP-Header.

So did you have any Idea and helps for my Code???

```
void startBuilding() {

    unsigned char *data;

    unsigned int packet_size;
    unsigned int data_size;

    src_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_aton(srcHost, &src_addr.sin_addr);

    dst_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_aton(destHost, &dst_addr.sin_addr);

    data = (char*) malloc(strlen(sendingData) + 1);

    strcpy((char *) data, sendingData);

    data_size = strlen(sendingData);

    switch (ipProto) {
    case IPPROTO_TCP:

        printf("[+] Send TCP packet...\n");

        src_addr.sin_port = htons(tcpSourcePort);
        dst_addr.sin_port = htons(tcpDestPort);

        if (open_RawSocket(ipProto)) {
            send_tcp_packet(raw_socket, src_addr, dst_addr, data, data_size);

        }

}



unsigned int build_tcp_packet(struct sockaddr_in src_addr,
    struct sockaddr_in dst_addr, unsigned char *tcp_packet,
    unsigned char *data, unsigned int data_size) {

    printf("[+] Build TCP packet...\n\n");

    unsigned int length;
    struct tcpheader *tcp;
    length = TCPHDRSIZE + data_size;
    tcp = (struct tcpheader *) tcp_packet;

    tcp->th_sport = src_addr.sin_port;
    tcp->th_dport = dst_addr.sin_port;

    tcp->th_seq = htonl(tcpSeqNum);
    tcp->th_acknum = tcpAcknum;

    tcp->th_reserved = tcpReserved;
    tcp->th_off = tcpOffSet;

    tcp->th_fin = tcpFinFlag;
    tcp->th_syn = tcpSynFlag;
    tcp->th_rst = tcpRstFlag;
    tcp->th_psh = tcpPshFlag;
    tcp->th_ack = tcpAckFlag;
    tcp->th_urg = tcpUrgFlag;
    tcp->th_cwr = tcpCwrFlag;
    tcp->th_ece = tcpEceFlag;

    tcp->th_win = htons(tcpWin);

    tcp->th_urp = tcpUrp;

    tcp->th_sum = tcpSum;

//      startSniffer(); // If i start startSniffer here, it works fine.
    memcpy(tcp_packet + TCPHDRSIZE, data, data_size);
//      startSniffer(); //If i start sartSniffer here, it did not work, and i get the error. 

    return length;
 }


unsigned int build_ip_packet(struct in_addr src_addr, struct in_addr dst_addr,
    uint8_t protocol, unsigned char *ip_packet, unsigned char *data,
    unsigned int data_size) {

    printf("[+] Build IP packet...\n\n");

    struct ipheader *ip;
    ip = (struct ipheader*) ip_packet;

    ip->ip_v = ipv;
    ip->ip_hl = iphl;

    ip->ip_tos = iptype;
    ip->ip_id = htons(ipId);

    if (calculateIpLenInBuildPacket) {
        ip->ip_len = htons(iphl * 4 + data_size);
    } else {
        ip->ip_len = htons(ipLen);
    }

    ip->ip_off = ipOffset;

    ip->ip_moreFrag = ipMoreFragmentFlag;
    ip->ip_doNotFrag = ipDoNotFragmentFlag;
    ip->ip_reserved = ipReserved;
    ip->ip_frag_offset1 = ipFragOffset;

    ip->ip_ttl = ipTTL;
    ip->ip_p = ipProto;

    ip->ip_sum = ipSum;
    ip->iph_sourceip = src_addr.s_addr;
    ip->iph_destip = dst_addr.s_addr;

    return sizeof(struct ipheader) + data_size;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    startBuilding();

    startSniffer();

}
```

---

```
void send_tcp_packet(int raw_sock, struct sockaddr_in src_addr,
    struct sockaddr_in dst_addr, uint8_t *data, unsigned int data_size) {
    unsigned int packet_size;
    unsigned int ip_payload_size;
    unsigned char *packet;


    packet = (char*) malloc(strlen(data) + 1);
    memset(packet, 0, ETH_DATA_LEN);



    ip_payload_size = build_tcp_packet(src_addr, dst_addr,
        packet + sizeof(struct ipheader), data, data_size);

    packet_size = build_ip_packet(src_addr.sin_addr, dst_addr.sin_addr,
    IPPROTO_TCP, packet, packet + sizeof(struct ipheader), ip_payload_size);

    setOption_RawSocket(raw_sock);

    if (sendto(raw_sock, packet, packet_size, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &dst_addr,
        sizeof(dst_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("sendto");

        exit(1);
    } else {

        printf("Send! \n\n");


    }
    close(raw_sock);

}
```

---

Comment: Please try to make a more minimal [mcve]. It should be possible to reduce this to a couple of misuses of malloc and free.

Comment: Your problem likely arises from corruption of the memory-management metadata.  Likely causes include overrunning dynamically-allocated buffers, double-freeing allocated memory, and continuing to use a pointer after its target has been freed.  Very likely this happens some time before the program actually crashes.  If you can't spot the problem through code analysis, then engaging a memory-use debugger such as Valgrind would be a good option.

Comment: You need to debug this. Probably there is a buffer overflow somewhere in your code. I suggest you have a close look at the `memcpy` you mention and check that you dont copy more bytes than allowed.

Comment: https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer is very useful for debugging problems like this.  It is part of GCC and easy to use.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Is it normal, that the code works fine, if i did not call `startSniffer()` ? This i confusing.

Comment: ASan is great.  Just a compile flag and it points you right to the memory problem.

Comment: @Craftables I try to configure AddressSanitizer

Comment: @MarkReedZ thanks, i try it with AddressSanitizer

Comment: @Sebastian, somewhere you have produced *undefined behavior* (for there is no defined behavior that would produce the outcome you describe).  There is no applicable sense of normalcy accompanying UB.  That you see this particular misbehavior only if you call `startSniffer()` *could* be a sign that the problem is contained within that function, but you cannot be certain of that.

Comment: Note that casing the return from `malloc` is not [best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) in C.  If you are using C++ compilation where the cast would be necessary, then better to use `new`.

Answer (score 2):

This is *dangerous*:

```
packet = (char*) malloc(strlen(data) + 1);
memset(packet, 0, ETH_DATA_LEN);
```

It will corrupt the heap whenever `ETH_DATA_LEN` is larger than `strlen(data) + 1`, the heap corruption will not be immediately detected but may cause subsequent allocations or deallocations (free) to fail.

Suggest:

```
packet = calloc( ETH_DATA_LEN, 1 ) ;
```

You made a rash assumption that `data` is a null terminated string and should have used  `data_size` to determine the length of `data` in any event, but since packet size is necessarily larger then just the data payload, both are incorrect.

You fail to free `packet` in this case, so also have a memory leak.  Since `ETH_DATA_LEN` is a constant, there is no need to dynamically allocate in any event.  Instead you might have:

```
char* packet[ETH_DATA_LEN] = {0} ;
```

Comment: @Sebastian :  Do what you like.  `calloc()` is not essential to the solution here, but if you are allocating then immediately memsetting to zero, it is safer since you then do not need to ensure your allocation and you memset are the same size - which was the error in this case.

Comment: Note that given the number of dangerous practices in just this one function, I would not suggest that I have spotted them all, and have not even looked at the other functions.

Comment: Actually i needed a dynamically allocate in any event. In order that the packet will sendet correctly. Is there a other method to create a dynamical variable, without a memory leak?....

Comment: got it. I initialize my packet one step befor i send the packet :))) if you wish, i could share the solution